# Generic subclass type casting with HashMap

Tags: java, generics, subclass, superclass

Okay so I have a superclass *Profile* and two subclasses *UserProfile* & *MovieProfile* which extends *Profile*.

I have a file with userprofiles and movieprofiles in a CSV format, and want to import these, and the information in these formats are the same, so therefor the code to import an HashMap of userprofiles and an HashMap of Movieprofiles are excatly the same, except i need to specify which type of profile it is.

**I have currently tried something like this:**

```
public <T> HashMap<Integer, T> importProfileList(String filePath, int totalGenomes, int totalGenres){
    CSV_Reader CSVR = new CSV_Reader(filePath);
    HashMap<Integer, T> profileHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (ArrayList<String> readLine : CSVR){
        Profile tempProfile = new Profile(-1, totalGenomes, totalGenres);
        tempProfile.importProfile(readLine, totalGenomes, totalGenres);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T profile = (T) tempProfile;

        profileHashMap.put(tempProfile.getID(), profile);
    }

    return profileHashMap;
}
```

But i just get an error, when i try to run the function in main, and try to access the elements.

"java.lang.ClassCastException: Profiles.Profile cannot be cast to Profiles.UserProfile"

**My code to generate *UserProfile* HashMap:**

```
public HashMap<Integer, UserProfile> importUserProfiles(String filePath, int totalGenomes, int totalGenres){
    CSV_Reader CSVR = new CSV_Reader(filePath);
    HashMap<Integer, UserProfile> profileHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (ArrayList<String> readLine : CSVR){
        UserProfile tempProfile = new UserProfile(-1, totalGenomes, totalGenres);
        tempProfile.importProfile(readLine, totalGenomes, totalGenres);

        profileHashMap.put(tempProfile.getID(), tempProfile);
    }

    return profileHashMap;
}
```

To generate an *MovieProfile* HashMap, you just have to switch every *UserProfile* with *MovieProfile* in the code above.

The code above is placed in a third object named *ProfileGenerator*.

**So my question goes:**

*How can I use the same code block for both my subclasses, possibly with generics? So I wont need "copy-paste code" in my program?*

Comment: It looks like you can create factory for each profile like `interface ProfileSupplier<T extends Profile>{ T create(...);} (I am not sure what arguments you want to use here, in your code you create profiles using `(-1, totalGenomes, totalGenres);` but later you invoke `tempProfile.importProfile(readLine, totalGenomes, totalGenres);` so maybe there should be constructor including `readLine` argument). Having such supplier would let you write `public <T extends Profile> HashMap<Integer, T> importProfileList(ProfileSupplier<T> supplier, [rest of arguments])`.

Comment: This would allow you to replace `Profile tempProfile = new Profile(-1, totalGenomes, totalGenres); .. T profile = (T) tempProfile;` with `T profile = supplier.create(arguments you decided in interface, possibly including data from `readLine`). You could use that method like `importProfileList(UserProfile::new, [rest of arguments])`.

Comment: Would this still allow me to call methods which are only present in UserProfile, and not Profile ?

Comment: No. If you want to make something general you need to accept also limitation of general case (so case which gathers what is common for every element).

Comment: Okay, but in that case I could just create an hashMap of Profile instead.